# Gulp concat multiples js modules into one js file

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have two javascripts files that need to run client-side. They use import and export statement. I need to concat them together into one file and minify it.

So I used gulp-minify and gulp-concat to do so. But the final script obviously doesn't work since it want import files that doesn't exist.

I really like working with javascript modules. Can I use gulp to have a single working file while using javascript modules from the source files ?

Comment: Look into https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-better-rollup and rollup in general.

Comment: This isn't what gulp is for and concatenation isn't the correct approach because it will produce invalid output as you've already seen. To accomplish this, there are dozens of transpilers and bundlers, once you have selected one, you can run it with gulp.